WPF VirtualizingStackPanel Text Wrapping issue after sort
I'm new to WPF and wrote this program to help with organising and cataloguing my books. I used a virtualizing wrap panel which displays perfectly until I sort the books.
Here is the view pre sort: Presorted Book List
Here is the view post sort: Sorted Book List
Here is the XAML for the DataTemplate:
<!-- DataTemplate for GridView -->
<DataTemplate x:Key="GridViewTemplate">
    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding FilteredBooks}"
          SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedBook, Mode=TwoWay}"
          SelectionChanged="OnBookSelected"
          VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizing="True" 
          VirtualizingStackPanel.VirtualizationMode="Recycling">
    <ListView.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <virtualizingWrapPanel:VirtualizingWrapPanel Orientation="Horizontal" />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemsPanel>
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Width="160" Margin="5" ToolTip="{Binding Title}">
                <Image Source="{Binding CoverImage}" Height="240" Width="160" Stretch="UniformToFill" Margin="0,0,0,5"/>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" TextAlignment="Center" FontWeight="Bold" TextWrapping="Wrap" />
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Author}" TextAlignment="Center" TextWrapping="Wrap" />
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>

and here is the function I used to sort the list.
public async Task FilterAndSortBooks()
{
    var result = await Task.Run(() =>
    {
        IEnumerable<Book> filtered = Books;

        // Apply filter based on the selected filter option
        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(SearchText))
        {
            filtered = SelectedFilter switch
            {
                "Title" => filtered.Where(book => book.Title.Contains(SearchText, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)),
                "Author" => filtered.Where(book => book.Author.Contains(SearchText, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)),
                "Release Year" => filtered.Where(book => book.Year.HasValue && book.Year.Value.ToString("yyyy").Contains(SearchText, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)),
                _ => filtered
            };
        }

        // Apply sorting based on the selected sort option
        filtered = SelectedSortOption switch
        {
            "Title" => filtered.OrderBy(book => book.Title),
            "Author" => filtered.OrderBy(book => book.Author),
            "Release Year" => filtered.OrderBy(book => book.Year),
            _ => filtered
        };

        return filtered.ToList();
    });

    // Update FilteredBooks on the UI thread
    Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
    {
        FilteredBooks.Clear();
        foreach (var book in result)
        {
            FilteredBooks.Add(book);
        }
    });
}

I want the sorted view to match the view presorted but can't figure out why it changes. Any help would be great.

Jsut to clarify, your issue is that Author is no longer displayed? Also I suggest to filter/sort and order collection via CollectionViewSource property

The title is also cut off not just the author

Look at the first item in the "WrapPanel" (first image). How does its "size" compare to all the items that follow it? Is it bigger or smaller?
In the absence of an explicit "item" Height and / or Width, the "first" item (size) in the collection drives the "desired size" for all following items.
So, insure all items are the same size; or, the big ones come first; or, using specific Widths and / or Heights.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.wrappanel.itemheight?view=windowsdesktop-8.0

That has fixed the issue. Is there a way to have it dynamically size to the largest item?

I typically hook the "Loaded" event of the control if I want to do any adjusting. In this case, you either iterate the .Children (after loading); or iterate the source before hand; in order to find the largest item and adjust the "WrapPanel's" item Height and Width properties (via code behind; or binding). Since this is "plumbing" (IMO), think code-behind before polluting any "view models". This assumes the control will let you change the Width / Height after loading. At the very least, an UpdateLayout() is probably needed ... after the fact.

I have for now just set it to the height that looks appropriate by default. It gives me something to work on if I decide to work on it in the future. Thanks for your help.

Yes ... "explicit" works; you asked about "dynamic". You can set the (item) size of the  items via the WrapPanel; or via the DataTemplate.
